# problems with setTimeout() repeating action

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have a variable that contains a string that I've `split()` into an array and use `shift()` method to print out one letter at a time to a `div`. I've used `setTimeout` to repeat the process and print out the entire string. The problem I'm having is that the function is printing out the first letter repeatedly without moving to the next letter in the string.
I've used the only ways I know of using setTimeout with parameters nothing seems to be working.

Where is the problem here in the code ?

```
<div id='ltrType'></div>
<script>
function buildWord(str) {
    var arr = str.split('');

    if(arr.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('ltrType').innerHTML += arr.shift();
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    //I've tried setTimeoout like this
    timer = setTimeout(buildWord,100,str);

    //and like this
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ buildWord(str); })
}

buildWord('this is another string blah blah blah');
```

Comment: `str` isn't changing from call to call. It is always the same string.

Comment: Every time it refreshes it is starting from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep passing in `str`, while it is `arr` that you shift. So basically you keep passing the same string every time, and the first character is the same every time. Instead, do it like this:

```
function buildWord(arr) {
    if (typeof arr === "string") {
        arr = arr.split('');
    } 
    if (arr.length) {
        document.getElementById('ltrType').innerHTML += arr.shift();
        setTimeout(function () {
            buildWord(arr);
        }, 100);
    }
}

buildWord('this is another string blah blah blah');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are building initial array each time on method call, move it outside

```
function buildWord(str)
{
   var arr = str.split(' ');

   var helper = function buildWordHelper()
   {       
        if(arr.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('ltrType').innerHTML += arr.shift();
       } else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
       }

       setTimeout(helper, 100);
   }
   setTimeout(helper, 100);
}

buildWord("bla bla1 bla123");
```

Comment: Your code is not correct. `str` is a parameter to the buildWord function. It cannot be split outside of the function. Your code assumes `str` is defined elsewhere.

Comment: oops, you are right, but no one prevent me to move string outside too... edited, now it at least will workg

Comment: True :) it works now, but the function has become useless... it will keep 'building' the same string every time. I assume the idea is this function can be used with any string :)

Comment: we can create another method, which take a string and call this function as underlying one... but well, agree, you method is better :)

Comment: sorry, SO won't yet let me remove the downvote. Can you edit your post again?

Answer (score 0):

beacuse arr is getting initalized everytime to the same value, you call buildword,again and again ,as you are passing str.Try putting it outside of function.

```
var arr=null;
var firsttime=0;
function buildWord(str)
{
if(firsttime==0)
{ arr=str.split('');firsttime=1;}
.....
}
```